# ERROR in Couldn't resolve original symbol for ./src/debug/debug_node

Tags: angular

I keep getting this error whenever clicking ng serve

```
 ERROR in Couldn't resolve original symbol for ./src/debug/debug_node from D:/.../Front/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts
```

However the application is working perfectly without any error and so i ignore it.
But now i need to find a solution because when running ng build --prod the error appears again and the files of publication didn't appear.

any solution?
and Thanks

Comment: is your core / cli up to date ?

Comment: Well i'm using Angular CLI: 6.2.9